# Act php file as a binary file for streaming audio song for iPhone

Tags: php

Here is my php code to act php file as a binary for streaming audio

```
try {
    if(file_exists($filePath)) {
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
        header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
        header('Content-length: ' . filesize($filePath));
        header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="$filePath"');
        header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        print readfile($filePath);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("File does not exist");
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
```

It's working on Mac Mini but not working at iPad and iPhone. Even streaming is working on other smart phone. Do i've to add anything to make it working on handheld device?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't work anywhere: [readfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) writes directly to output, so you don't print or echo it.

```
print readfile($filePath);
```

should be

```
readfile($filePath);
```

Echoing/Printing as well gives you spurious extra characters (the number of bytes in the file)

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply...
Changed to readfile($filePath); but still it's not working....